# Pass variable value from JavaScript function to SQL query AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am making a serverless phone directory search application.
There are two files: index.html and lambda_function.py

The index.html has a JS function, a text field for entering a name, and a search button. Lambda_function.py contains
code for handling CSV.

I am unable to pass values from the index.html textbox to the lambda_function.py SQL query.
The browser debugger reports an error.

```
errorMessage: "name 'name_Person' is not defined"
​
errorType: "NameError"
​
stackTrace: Array [ "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    sql_q = \"SELECT * FROM s3object s where s.\\\"Name\\\" = ('%s')\" %name_Person\n" ]
```

What is the correct way to pass the name entered by the user into the SQL query in this case?

Index.html content

```
<script>

    function FindInPhoneBook() {
        var name_person = $('#name').val();
        if (name_person == "")
            return;
        fetch('https://xxx.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/SecondStage', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: '{ "command": "find", "name_Person":"'+name_person+'" }'
        }).then(function(data) {
            $('#list_personal').val(data)
            find();
            data.json().then(function(bodyData) {
                console.log(bodyData);
                $('#list_personal').text(bodyData);
            })
        })
    }
        
</script>
<div class = "border">


<input id="name" type="text">
<button onclick="FindInPhoneBook()">
Find
</button>  
<br></br>
<div id='list_personal'></div>
</div>

lambda_function.py content
```

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    res = ''
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    if(len(event) == 0):
        with open('index.html','r') as file:
            return file.read()
    elif event['command'] == 'find':
        #name = 'Vinod'
        sql_q = "SELECT * FROM s3object s where s.\"Name\" = ('%s')" %name_Person
        resp = s3.select_object_content(
            Bucket='chumbacket',
            Key='sample_data.csv',
            ExpressionType='SQL',
            Expression=sql_q,
            InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
            OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
        )
        
        for event in resp['Payload']:
            if 'Records' in event:
                records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
            
        return records
    elif 1==1:
        pass
        
    return res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to define your `name_Person` variable. Try adding this before the SQL query:

```
name_Person = event['name_Person']
```

Since it seems like you `elif event['command'] == 'find':` conditional is triggering fine, the event should have `name_Person` in there too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data to a Lambda function by invoking the Lambda function using the Lambda API and calling the **invoke** method. You can pass data to it as JSON data. Here is an example implemented in Java (but will show you how to use the Lambda API to invoke a Lambda operation and pass data)

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/lambda/src/main/java/com/example/lambda/LambdaInvoke.java

You can see AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 AWS Lambda examples here. This is the API to use from within a script tag in your HTML.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascriptv3/example_code/lambda